# Using the same Data Extension for multiple Journeys Processing Power

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, builder

I understand that you should not use the same DE for multiple journeys if this automation is run continuously on a daily basis and the journey is constantly recorruring.

BUT can I use 1 de for multiple journeys if this Data extension is overwritten and the journey NEVER repeats?

I have multiple journeys from the past that are still "running" but they were one-off sends that use the same de but are not connected to any automations.  I then create a new journey - insert this same DE that was "overwritten" and send out whenever needed.

Does this impact journey performance?

OR

Should I create a new DE for each journey sendout?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new data extension for each journey or consolidate the journey into one journey. Entering the same contact into multiple journeys can cause the contact to receive duplicate emails. Creating separate data extensions makes it easier to scale and troubleshoot.

One-off sends not connected to any automations can be deactivated if it is no longer in use. I don't see a reason to keeping them running for no reason.